Can suddenly register for events without validating email address
On testing a new event form, we have discovered, by accident, that we can complete the registration form without a valid email address.  The email address is required, so the field has to have something in it, but it doesn't have to be a valid email address. Same for the phone number field, although it's not require, it doesn't have to be a phone number.
This form: https://birthmark.org/pan  is using the "New Individual" reserved profile for the name, email, and phone.  This same form, without the WP shortcode is here https://birthmark.org/civicrm/event/register/?reset=1&id=29, but the behavior is the same (to rule out a shortcode error).
Error logs for the site do not show any errors related to this.  Civi error logs also don't have any errors.  Console shows a few warnings, but they are related to fonts and image preloading.
This is not happening in contribution pages, only event registrations.
I'm not sure what my next troubleshooting step should be, without any errors to guide me. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
I have disabled all the extensions that I possibly can to rule those out.  I have disabled all custom templates.
WordPress 6.6.2
CiviCRM 5.78.3


You say 'suddenly'. do you mean you. believe that email fields were going through some form of validation and that this has now stopped working (which i don't believe is the case, ie that email fields in civi forms have never gone through some form of validation and just retested on dmaster and it allowed both demo@example and demoexample to go through which not valid

Pete, if I don't put an entry with a @into the email field on the contribution form, I get an error message that says, Please enter a valid email address. and the form wont' submit.  The event registration form used to be the same way, but now is not.

Looking at a 5.69 site, it does seem to validate the email. So yeah seems like a bug got introduced somewhere.

I've created a ticket https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5587. It seems to have happened between 5.74 and 5.75.

Thank you.  In the meantime, I'm not sure how to fix it so that people can register for our events.

do you mean how they register while mis-entering email addresses? or are you saying the form totally doesn't work currently?

The form works, but the user can submit the form without a valid email address.  Most of our events require a receipt (we do some zoom meetings, and the zoom link is in the receipt) so it's a problem if they don't get it.  It does happen that someone puts in the wrong email address, but we can usually figure that out.

I put in an ugly piece of js to change the field type to email, so that they get at least a warning if they haven't entered a valid email address.

There's a potential patch listed in the ticket now. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31455/files
